# Enum datatype versus table of data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have one MySQL table, `users`, with the following columns:

1. user_id (PK)
2. email
3. name
4. password

To manage a roles system, **would there be a downside to either of the following options?**

**Option 1:**

Create a second table called `roles` with three columns: `role_id` (Primary key), `name`, and `description`, then associate `users.user_id` with `roles.role_id` as foreign keys in a third table called `users_roles`?

Or...

**Option 2:**

Create a second table called `roles` with two columns: `user_id` (Foreign key from `users.user_id`) and `role` (ENUM)? The ENUM datatype column would allow for a short list of allowable roles to be inserted as values.

I've never used the ENUM datatype in MySQL before, so I'm just curious, as option 2 would mean one less table. I hope that makes sense, this is the first time I've attempted to describe MySQL tables in a forum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, `ENUM` types are not meant to be used in these situations. This is especially the case if you intend to cater for the flexibility of adding or removing roles in the future. The only way to change the values of an `ENUM` is with an `ALTER TABLE`, while defining the roles in their own table will simply require a new row in the `roles` table.

In addition, using the `roles` table allows you to add additional columns to better define the role, like the `description` field you suggested in Option 1. This is not possible if you were to use an `ENUM` type as in Option 2.

Personally I would not opt for an `ENUM` in these scenarios. Maybe I can see them being used for columns with an absolutely finite set of values, such as `{Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs}` to define the suit of a card, but not in cases such as the one in question, for the disadvantages mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks! You did a great job of explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Using ENUM for the case You suggested only makes sense when You have a strictly definded ORM on the receiving end that for istance maps db rows into a list of flat objects automatically.

Example:
table animal( ENUM('reptiles','mamals') Category, (varchar 50)Name );

is automatically maped to

object animal
  animal->Category
  animal->Name